# What am I missing for this CQ5/AEM URL rewriting scenario?

Tags: aem, sling

I basically want short URLs to get resolved and HTML pages to be generated with short URLs for a CQ5 website. So far short URLs are getting mapped to long URLs as expected, but links in the generated HTML pages are not getting shortened.

For example, I am expecting the `src` attribute of the following `<script>` tag:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/content/foo/c0/06/9d/3d93a858-efb4-4619-8f9e-5edc65d0f5ae/style/clientlibs.1395978029951.js"></script>
```

To be shortened to:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/style/clientlibs.1395978029951.js"></script>
```

But it is not and remains intact. `href` attributes in anchor elements are not getting shortened either.

In JCR, the website is stored under `/content/foo/c0/06/9d/3d93a858-efb4-4619-8f9e-5edc65d0f5ae/` and I have configured my `/etc/hosts` and Apache config files to make it accessible via `http://site-1:4503` in my local development environment.

I have defined the following URL mappings:

```
{
   "jcr:primaryType":"sling:Folder",
   "http":{
      "jcr:primaryType":"sling:Folder",
      "site-1.4503":{
         "sling:internalRedirect":[
            "/content/foo/c0/06/9d/3d93a858-efb4-4619-8f9e-5edc65d0f5ae"
         ],
         "jcr:primaryType":"sling:Mapping",
         "redirect":{
            "sling:internalRedirect":[
               "/content/foo/c0/06/9d/3d93a858-efb4-4619-8f9e-5edc65d0f5ae/$1",
               "/$1"
            ],
            "jcr:primaryType":"sling:Mapping",
            "sling:match":"(.+)$"
         }
      },
      "site_1.4503":{
         "sling:internalRedirect":[
            "/content/foo/c0/06/9d/3d93a858-efb4-4619-8f9e-5edc65d0f5ae/home.html"
         ],
         "jcr:primaryType":"sling:Mapping",
         "sling:match":"site-1.4503/$"
      }
   }
}
```

When I test this mapping in JCR Resolver (`http://localhost:4503/system/console/jcrresolver`), it is working as expected. For example,

```
/content/foo/c0/06/9d/3d93a858-efb4-4619-8f9e-5edc65d0f5ae/style/clientlibs.1395978029951.js
```

is mapped to

```
http://site-1:4503/style/clientlibs.1395978029951.js
```

and

```
http://site-1:4503/style/clientlibs.1395978029951.js
```

is resolved to:

```
JcrNodeResource, 
type=cq:ClientLibraryFolder,
superType=null, 
path=/content/foo/c0/06/9d/3d93a858-efb4-4619-8f9e-5edc65d0f5ae/style/clientlibs
```

Also when I go to `http://site-1:4503/style/clientlibs.1395978029951.js` in my browser, the JS file is rendered as expected.

However when I view the HTML source for the home page, as I mentioned earlier, none of the long URLs are rewritten to their shortened forms.

Any ideas what am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We finally managed to pinpoint the issue and fix this.

Somebody had added a `com.day.cq.rewriter.linkchecker.impl.LinkCheckerImpl.xml` under `/apps/myapp/config.publish` with the following content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jcr:root xmlns:sling="http://sling.apache.org/jcr/sling/1.0" xmlns:jcr="http://www.jcp.org/jcr/1.0"
    jcr:primaryType="sling:OsgiConfig"
    service.bad_link_tolerance_interval="{Long}48"
    service.check_override_patterns="[^.]"
    service.special_link_patterns=".*&#xa;"
    service.special_link_prefix="[javascript:,data:,mailto:,#,&lt;!--,${]"/>
```

I think the combination of `check_override_patterns` and `special_link_patterns` had disabled link shortening.

Removing this file made link shortening work again.

Answer (score 3):

By default, CQ rewrites links in `a`, `area` and `form` tags. If you'd like to rewrite also paths in `script` tag, open OSGi configuration for `LinkCheckerTransformerFactory` service on publish and add following string to the **Rewrite Elements** option:

```
script:src
```

BTW: `/content` is not the best place for storing clientlibs. Usually we put this stuff in `/etc/designs/YOUR_APP`.

Comment: Tomek, thanks for the reply. However, as I have mentioned in my question, even `href`s of anchor elements are not being rewritten. I'll have a look at our `LinkCheckerTransformerFactory`'s config tomorrow to see if anything is out of order there.

Comment: I double checked our `Day CQ Link Checker Transformer`s configuration and it is configured properly. I added `script:src` to rewrite elements but it still is not kicking in.

Comment: Tomek, does `LinkCheckerTransformerFactory` only rewrite links that are "broken"? [This](http://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/kb/DisableLinkChecker.html) somehow makes one think so. Or does it also convert long URLs to short URLs (e.g. /content/foo/home.html to /home.html)?

Comment: It does both. Two checkboxes in its configuration allows to disable broken link checking and link rewriting (as these transformations are enabled by default).

Comment: Tomek, any ideas why links that end up with .css or .js, are not getting shortened, even when they are inside an anchor tag (e.g. `<a href="/content/..../clientlibs/foo.js">Test<a>`)?

Comment: Tomek, what are some problems that might arise if we put client libs under `/content/appName`? Or is it just a convention to store them under `/etc/designs/appName`?