# Rewrite Adobe CQ Image src attribute

Tags: aem, sling

In AEM, content such as pages and images contains the `'/content/'` prefix in them. We are able to rewrite these url via **Link Checker Transformer** configuration and `resourceResolver.map()` method. URLs are being rewritten for HTML elements `<a>` and `<form>`.

But I want it to work for `<img>` elements as well.

I tried including the `<img>` elements to the Link Checker Transformer configuration by adding it to the 'Rewrite Elements' list as **`img:src`**:

[image]

I also checked the answers from **[What am I missing for this CQ5/AEM URL rewriting scenario?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22707466/what-am-i-missing-for-this-cq5-aem-url-rewriting-scenario)** but both attempts didn't work for this issue.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: have you configured the rewriter in /apps/XXX/config/rewriter ?

Comment: @santiagozky unfortunately no. i will read up on how to configure the rewriter through that.

Comment: @santiagozky i tried it but nothing happens to `<img>` elements

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even if the `rewriter` and `Link Checker Transformer` didn't work. I used a custom LinkRewriter by using the `Transformer` and `TransformerFactory` interfaces. I based on the sample from [Adobe](https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/using/creating-link-rewrite.html) for my code. I worked out something like this:

```
@Component(
     metatype = true,
     label = "Image Link Rewriter",
     description = "Maps the <img> elements src attributes"
)
@Service(value = TransformerFactory.class)
@Property(value = "global", propertyPrivate = true)
public class ImageLinkRewriter implements Transformer, TransformerFactory {

    // some variables

    public CustomLinkTransformer() {  }

    @Override
    public void init(ProcessingContext context,
                     ProcessingComponentConfiguration config) throws IOException {
        // initializations here
    }

    @Override
    public final Transformer createTransformer() {
        return new CustomLinkTransformer();
    }

    @Override
    public void startElement(String uri, String localName, 
                             String qName, Attributes atts) throws SAXException {
        if ("img".equalsIgnoreCase(localName)) {
            contentHandler.startElement(uri, localName, qName, rewriteImageLink(atts));
        }
    }

    private Attributes rewriteImageLink(Attributes attrs) {
        String attrName = "src";
        AttributesImpl result = new AttributesImpl(attrs);

        String link = attrs.getValue(attrName);
        String mappedLink = resource.getResourceResolver().map(request, link);

        result.setValue(result.getIndex(attrName), mappedLink);

        return result;
    }

}
```

Hope this helps others. Here are a few references:

- [TransformerFactory interface](https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/cq/5-6-1/javadoc/org/apache/sling/rewriter/TransformerFactory.html)
- [Transformer interface](https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/cq/5-6-1/javadoc/org/apache/sling/rewriter/Transformer.html)
- [Adobe](https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/using/creating-link-rewrite.html)

Comment: For anybody coming here: The source code in this answer is a bit messed up. For a complete working example see this gist I created: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/d2a22bdf0dfc5549b41b825abe65c7a3